# Transform any linear program to its standard form used in interior point solvers

Tags: linear-programming, interior-point-method

I have programmed the primal-dual simplex method as explained [here](http://www.4er.org/CourseNotes/Book%20B/B-III.pdf).

The method requires the information to be passed in the standard form:

$$
min:\quad c^\top \cdot x\\
s.t.:\\
A·x = b\\
x \geq 0
$$

However, most solvers offer an interface to pass the data in the following format, which is quite generic and convenient:

$$
min:\quad c^\top \cdot x\\
s.t.:\\
Ub \leq A·x \leq Ub\\
lb \leq x \leq ub
$$

**How can I convert this format to the standard form accepted by the interior point method?**

Comment: Did you instead mean $x \ge 0$?  And $L \le Ax \le U$?

Comment: You started out discussing primal-dual simplex and shifted at the end to interior point method. Was that intentional or do you really mean primal-dual?

Comment: @RobPratt I have just edited X to be positive, but the restrictions I mean them like that since that is what the interior point method "wants"

Comment: @prubin no simplex at all, so it was intentional. There is an interior point method called primal-dual interior point (see the reference)

Comment: See section 10.3 in the note by Bob Fourer you refer to.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK Indeed, but that is a partial example, I'd like to have a complete list of issues. Plus, is that really what solvers do internally?

Comment: All you need is the idea in Section 10.3 i.e. use of slack variables.

Comment: what if `Ub` is negative, should I not change the sign of the corresponding row of A? How should I handle the bounds of x other than `0 <= x <= infinity`?